# Question about writing amplitude for electron vertex correction

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions

In Peskin and Schroeder, they write down the amplitude for the following diagram as 6.38

[image]

Why does the propagator for the photon with momentum $q$ never show up in the amplitude? Why is it ignored?

Comment: For the same reason there's no electron propagator with momentum $p$ or $p'$. Those are external particles.

Comment: So do we work with diagrams where we ignore the external legs?

Answer (score 2):

The 3-point function in eq. (6.38) is the *amputated* 1PI vertex function. See also the general discussion around eq. (4.90) and eq. (4.103).